# Unable to save to in GeoJSON format with the correct projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geojson

I have a shapefile (Polygon) in QGIS that I wish to save in GeoJSON in order to display it with the mapbox JavaScript API. Original projection is in POSGAR 97.

My issue is that it does not reproject when I set projection to WGS84. Even if in the T.O.C I set the projection to WGS84 and **Save As**. Even if I uncheck the on the fly re-projection.

This is how coordinate looks like:

```
"coordinates": [ [ [ 324345.0, -3579435.0 ]
```

It should looks like:

```
"coordinates": [ [ [ -32.43450, -35.794350 ]
```

Curious think is if I **Save As** in KML, it works and the point of the polygon looks like:

```
<coordinates>-64.866399861691903,-32.338025763844477...
```

Comment: What version are you using of QGIS? It might be a bug you can report at hub.qgis.org

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.4 (not sure about previous versions), when you right-click on the layer and choose "Save As...".  On the "Save vector layer as..." dialog, be sure to change the CRS dropdown from "Layer CRS" to "Selected CRS" and then browse to "WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (EPSG: 3857)".

Everything else should work the same and give you the output you expect.[image]